# QOpenGLFramebufferObject bind texture

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, framebuffer

This is totally driving me nuts!

I've created my fbo by

```
QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat format;
format.setAttachment(QOpenGLFramebufferObject::CombinedDepthStencil);
format.setMipmap(false);
format.setSamples(4);
format.setTextureTarget(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
format.setInternalTextureFormat(GL_RGBA32F_ARB);
qfbo=new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(QSize(w,h),format);
```

ok it seems to be working and Qt doesn't claim about that.

The problem is that I need that QOpenGLFramebufferObject as read/write, write on it seems to be easy, just qfbo.bind() makes its work, the problem is that I cannot bind its texture, if I ask it about GLuint handle it always return 0 in both modes:

```
qDebug()<<qfbo->texture();
qDebug()<<qfbo->takeTexture();
```

obviously my intention is to bind the texture by itself like:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, fbo->texture());
```

Any tip about this? I've been googling for a long time without luck :(

I forget to say that if I don't use .setsamples(4); get a !=0 GLuit but totally black.

Comment: When I check the documentation for `texture()` its says: "If a multisample framebuffer object is used then the value returned from this function will be invalid." So my guess is that if you don't use `setsamples(4)` its working, but the drawing is just black.http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglframebufferobject.html#texture

Comment: Yes as I said without it it returns 0 as GLuint but with it (setsamples(4)) it returns 0 as GLuint

Answer (score 2):

If you use multisampling, there's no texture allocated, instead a multisampled renderbuffer gets used.

You need to create another, non multisampled FBO of matching dimensions and use `blitFramebuffer` to resolve the multisampled data into single sampled. 
Then you'll have the texture you can bind (to the `2D` target, not to the `1D`!). If this texture is still full black, run apitrace on your code and see what you're doing wrong.